# C3.js: Tooltip is still displayed after deleting circle

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I removed all circles from chart

```
d3.selectAll('circle').remove();
```

But when I hover over an invisible point, I can still see the tooltip
[image]

Disable tooltip for the all chart I can't
Who knows how to turn off an event for an invisible point?

pointer-events - did not work for me

```
circle.style('pointer-events', 'none')
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if a point is invisible, it will trigger mouse events. Two solutions come to mind:

1. Hide the point using the CSS style `display: none;` This will remove the point from the DOM and therefore prevent a mouseenter/mouseover event.
2. Add a check to your tooltip code to check if the current element is invisible or not (if you're using d3-tip, just create a wrapper for tooltip.show() with the added conditional)